# How Do I make my Explosions Append At My Enemy x and y? Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

[Video](https://gyazo.com/79b819ac97d29063ef620a31a9ecb42f) as you can see in the video the smoke appears somewhere else instead of the enemies x and y if I scroll and go kill the other [enemy](https://gyazo.com/4e0a4fce322dfba42f67b3f8070c16cf) the smoke appears back where it was

in my reDraw Window I said if my enemies health is greater then -3 then show the explodes
but how can I make it appear in the enemies x and y?

```
            for enemys in enemying:
                if enemys.health < -3:
                    for explode in explodes:
                        explode.draw()
```

this is where I delete the enemys when they die

```
                # enemys 2
            for enemyshoot in enemyshooting:
                for bullet in bullets:
                    if bullet.rect.colliderect(enemyshoot.hitbox):
                        if enemyshoot.health > -8:
                            enemyshoot.health -= 1
                            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                        else:
                            del enemyshooting[one]
```

this is my full explosion class

```
class explode:
        
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.explode = [
            pygame.image.load("smoke1.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke2.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke3.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke4.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke5.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke6.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke7.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke8.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke9.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke10.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke11.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke12.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke13.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke14.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke15.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke16.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke17.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke18.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke19.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke20.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke21.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke22.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke23.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke24.png"),
            pygame.image.load("smoke25.png")]

            self.explode = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//2,image.get_height()//2)) for image in self.explode]

            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            self.direction = "blobright"
            self.anim_index = 0
        def draw(self):
             
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            if self.direction == "blobright":
                window.blit(self.explode[self.anim_index], self.rect)
                self.anim_index += 1
                if self.anim_index == len(self.explode):
                    self.anim_index = 0
            



    black = (0,0,0)
    explode1 = explode(400,450,50,50,black)
    explodes = [explode1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is right in your code:

```
    black = (0,0,0)
    explode1 = explode(400,450,50,50,black)
    explodes = [explode1]
```

When you create the explosion to draw, you set its explosion location immediately. No matter where the enemy is when it dies, the explosion will always be drawn at that (400,450) because that's where you set it to explode.

You need to tell the explosion where to draw itself when the enemy dies, not when the explosion is instantiated. What I would do is instead of giving the explode class its own stored x and y, just add x,y parameters to the draw() function, and pass the coordinates of the dying enemy at the time of its death. It would look something like this:

```
#Modified explode.draw() function:
        def draw(self,drawX,drawY):
             
            self.rect.topleft = (drawX,drawY)
            if self.direction == "blobright":
                window.blit(self.explode[self.anim_index], self.rect)
                self.anim_index += 1
                if self.anim_index == len(self.explode):
                    self.anim_index = 0

#Modified death loop
            for enemys in enemying:
                if enemys.health < -3:
                    for explode in explodes:
                        explode.draw(enemys.x,enemys.y)
```

Hope this helps!